# Azure AD can't login with valid email if user was previously logged in to azure with another email (which doesn't belong to the tenant)

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

So we use msal-js library to add sso login to our site. We use this simple object for the msal-js configuration.

```
const config = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_TENANT_ID}`,
    redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECTURI,
    
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage"
  }
};
```

The login works correctly except for the following occasion.
(The root of the issue is that azure AD sso login shows and cares about emails from different tenants)

- User opens google chrome browser and logins to another site with azure AD sso (not our tenant) let's say https://myaccount.microsoft.com/ with email aa@xxxx.com.
- User opens a new tab and tries to login to our site with azure AD sso with email bb@xxxx.com (if he didn't do step 1 it would be ok).
- Microsoft pop up appears and he tries to choose account bb@xxx.com but because azure has already the aa@gmail.com as loggedin he gets an error for the valid bb@xxx.com email.

[image]

If i choose use another account and type the bb@xxx.com email i get the same error message again "There was a problem searching for your account. Click Next to try again.

Is there something that can be added to the config object in order to fix that? Maybe something that states "care only about emails that belong to our tenant id or application id"? aa@xxx.com does not belong to our tenantid or app id.

PS: The pop up texts are translated from another language to english so they might not be 100% accurate

Comment: What is your `REACT_APP_AUTHORITY`? Is it a tenant ID?

Comment: Yes it is a tenant id

Comment: Hmm... When it redirects to that login page, does it have the tenant ID in the URL?

Comment: yes it has it. The login works perfectly if i open incognito for example (so it doesn't remember the aa@xxx.com email)

Comment: @prof chaos : Have you got a  chance to check this- [SSO between browser tabs for the same app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#sso-between-different-apps)  :To make sure authorization server checks for the correct account session, you can pass one of the following options `Session ID` , `login_hint` or by accounts ( `msallInstance.getAccountByHomeId(homeAccountId);` )   in the request object of the ssoSilent method to obtain the token silently.